# In-App Purchase cannot change status Ready to Submit to Wait for Review

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I registered In-App Purchases and there are **Ready to Submit**. I want make their status **Wait for Review** but there are no ways for make it.

follow more details

- I have succeessed to change status to "Wait for Review" one of them before, **just one time**.
- I want to change status others, but I could not.
- Submit for Review button are always disabled.
- In "View Details", appear messages that :

  "In-App Purchases cannot be added to this version because it has already been submitted for review. To manage your In-App Purchases, go back to the App Summary page and click on the Manage In-App Purchases button."

In result,  I have no idea to solving this problem. I read thousand articles about message above, but not works for me. Most answers say that just edit something in the "**View Detalis**" page. I know the answer is right but not effective in my case.

please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created a container in iTunes connect, you can click a button "ready for upload". That means your itunes connect is now expecting you to create an archive of your product and submit for review using Xcode.

To get from "Waiting for binary" to "waiting for review" is to submit your binary archive from Xcode.

Comment: my app is work perfectly for just one In-App Purchase item that I made it to Wait for Review before, is not requires upload binary when test in devices. My problem is why it cannot make other items to status "Wait for Review". Why it succeessed just one time?

Comment: Maybe send Apple a support email, asking why you can't submit multiple in-app purchase content for review.

Answer (score 0):

I've just solved the same problem about 5 mins ago.

This is how my app looks like on https://itunesconnect.apple.com

![From Manage ou apps menu - Manage in-app purchases][1]

The trick was to use correct Bundle ID (from App) an ProductId (from image). It should work even though status is: Waiting for review and the binary has not been yet uploaded.

[Good troubleshooting tutorial](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem - inactive Submit button in IAP section in AppStoreConnect.

The 1st thing is mandatory screenshot in the Review information (text on the right is not mandatory). When I add a screenshot, the message "Missing metadata" for IAP disappears. But IAP submit button was inactive.

Second, I was submitted my binary for review before add this screenshot for the IAP. The most important thing here is that when the IAP is ready for review stage, you should go to your app (App Store tab), scroll down the page until you see the In-App Purchases section, click blue + button and add your IAP you created before.

So, this Submit button in IAP (in the Features section) is not needed.
IAP, when is selected in the app section, changed his status to "Waiting for Review" automatically, together with the app submission and status change to "Waiting for Review"..